# How to resynchronize all blocks using `bitcoin-cli`?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client

Sometimes, I need to resynchronize all blocks using bitcoin core, but I want to do that through `bitcoin-cli`. I found a command called `-rescan` that may resolve my question on this site, but as I searched the api list of bitcoin on the official site for 
`-rescan`, I couldn't find it out, therefore, I want to make it sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-rescan` is for your wallet. It will check for missing transactions on startup. If you want to resynchronize all blocks then I think you want to use `-reindex` which will rebuild chain state and block index from the blk*.dat files on disk. Of course, these are command line parameters.

You can probably use `verifychain` on bitcoin-cli. Type `bitcoin-cli help verifychain` for information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `-rescan` will rescan whole the entire blockchain and `-reindex` will rebuild your database